# How do I access Request.cookies in an ASP.NET MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get a user ID stored in cookies via a common Controller file, which I can access throughout the site.

I have created `FunctionsController` as a controller, with content as follows:

```
public static int loggedinUser()
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(  request.Cookies["userid"].Value);
}
```

I am unable to request any cookie items even if I tried with:

```
HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
```

Answer (score 41):

I don't have a problem accessing cookies in ASP.NET MVC using a standard access statement such as:

```
Request.Cookies["someCookie"]
```

Your sample had a lower-cased "r" in "request.Cookies".  Could that be your problem?

Comment: it says An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Request.get'

Comment: using System;using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;using ystem.Web;using System.Web.Mvc;using CRM.Models;
namespace MarcelCRM.Controllers
{    public class FunctionsController : Controller
    { public static int loggedinUser() {return Convert.ToInt32(Request.Cookies["someCookie"]); }}}

Answer (score 11):

Remove the `static` part of your method declaration and then use `Request.Cookies["userId"]`

Comment: Regarding to his exception, this is propably the answer.